# in search of different zemiros tunes

Tags: shabbat-songs

I'm looking for new non standard tunes for zemiros. For example i really like the dror yikra sang to simon and garfunkels scarborough fair (if you're interested i found someone has it up on youtube here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea1m-HDZ6xM). I would really like to find more zemiros that have good tunes put to them. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you know this site? http://www.zemirotdatabase.org

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lirCAN0OXNs

Answer (score 1):

As long as you've already delved into sticking with two Jewish boys from the 60's for creating a tune for a Moroccan who wrote poetry about a millennium earlier, you can try singing the same words to the tune of either "Sloop John B." by the Beach Boys or the tune of "The Adams Family" (I don't know who wrote that.)

My advice - stick with the "classical" Shabbat "Jewish" tunes. If you try a bit, just about any tune in 4/4 meter can fit anything you like. It doesn't mean I would sing "Eishat Chayil" to the tune of "Witchy Woman".

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of resources in the net where you can find different versions of the popular songs.

I use soundcloud.com a lot. If you like niggunim then check out http://audio.chassidus.com/audio/enign/